# RangeError: Invalid status code: 0 in Express App - Session issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I have this random error on a express app:

```
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/project-folder/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:573:10)
    at writeend (/project-folder/node_modules/express-session/index.js:257:22)
    at Immediate.onsave [as _onImmediate] (/project-folder/node_modules/express-session/index.js:325:11)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

I tried to fix it by doing something like this with no luck:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.on("end", function() {
        if (res.statusCode < 100 && res.statusCode >= 600) {
          res.status(500);          
        }
    });
    next();
});
```

I have no idea where to find the error or at least put a try catch, the error is random and the trace is not very explicit.

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but why are you calling `next()` immediately if you might be changing the status code at a later point in time (when the request finishes)? It seems you like should delay calling `next()` until the request finishes.

Comment: Yeah, I was unsure about this, but I found that code as a solution somewhere else in a related question.

But, after all, I found that my problem was related with some request with long timeouts. When the request failed, it returned false or null, which is 0 when you parse it as integer, so, I was not validating this case.

So, if the response is null or false, I return 504 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar error when switching between two projects that I am hosting on localhost for development and testing. Manually deleting the cookies for localhost in the browser solved the problem for me.
I used your function to find out. Printing out req.headers for all requests made me realise that the cookies were persisting when switching between different projects on localhost.